# How to get newer version of Ruby into gem environment

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I've installed Ruby 2.2.2 with rbenv. However when I run

```
gem env
```

it says that I am using 2.0.0. I read on a different question to run

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin --no-ri --no-rdoc bundler
rbenv rehash
bundle --path=vendor/bundle
```

However, when running the last line, I receive the error:

```
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

How do I get the system to use Ruby 2.2.2?

EDIT:
I printed out the contents of my .bash_profile and it had the following two lines:

```
export PATH
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

Is it bad that there is a blank export PATH? If so, how do I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Ruby 2.2.2 installed already, you can use `renv global`

```
rbenv global 2.2.2
```

Check out the documentation [here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/21545-rbenv-how-to-switch-to-another-ruby-version-temporarily-per-project-or-globally).

Comment: I tried that, but then when I try to run "sudo gem install rack -v 2.0.1", which "bundle update" tells me I need to run, It says that it requires Ruby version 2.2.2 or greater

Comment: Can you type `rbenv -v` and tell me the output?

Comment: rbenv 1.0.0-21-g9fdce5d

Comment: What happens when you run `rbenv install 2.2.2` followed by `rbenv global 2.2.2`?

Comment: When I run 'rbenv install 2.2.2' it shows '/Users/<redacted>/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2 already exists'. I then run 'rbenv global 2.2.2' but 'gem env' still shows that I'm using 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

It turns out RVM was still present in the system. All I had to do was run:

```
rvmsudo rvm implode
```